# how to extract number (X>=0)

Tags: r

I have a question.
I would like to get a dataframe like df2, but the following `destring` code does not work.....

```
library(taRifx)

df$id<-destring(df$id, keep = "0-9")
```

This code gives me 1234,2838, 34561,34571, 3456

```
df<-data.frame(id=c("X1234","D2838","3456.1","F3457.1","3456"))
class(df$id)

df2<-data.frame(id=c("1234","2838","3456","3457","3456"))

df$id<-destring(df$id, keep = "0-9")
```

Comment: where did `destring()` come from?

Comment: Sorry, it is from library(taRifx).

Comment: Does it need to be rounded, or should the code extract the `floor`? (what if element 3 was 3456.9?)

Answer (score 2):

You can try `sub`,

```
sub('[A-Za-z]?([0-9]+)\\.?.*', '\\1', df$id)
#[1] "1234" "2838" "3456" "3457" "3456"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question - the main problem is you want to drop the decimal places. If so, then keep the default `keep=` arguments, and use something like`round()`, `floor()`, or `as.integer()` function.

`df$id<-as.integer(destring(df$id, keep = "0-9.-"))`

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/taRifx/taRifx.pdf

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is for your objective, but worthy a try

```
gsub(".*?(\\d+)","\\1",df$id)
```

such that

```
> gsub(".*?(\\d+)","\\1",df$id)
[1] "1234"  "2838"  "34561" "34571" "3456"
```